# Trying to center align UL but the width defaults to 100%

Tags: html, css, html-lists

http://anaya.sonikastudios.com/

The HTML:

```
<div id="menubar" class="grid_12 alpha omega">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#" title="Diamond Engagement Ring Sets">Engagement Sets</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Diamond Solitaires">Solitaires</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Diamond Three Stone Rings">Three Stone Rings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Diamond Anniversary Rings">Anniversary Rings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Diamond Gentleman's Rings">Gent's Rings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Diamond Earrings">Earrings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Diamond Pendants">Pendants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Diamond Bracelets">Bracelets</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Very simple, really.

Then we have the CSS:

```
#menubar {
    height: 22px;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background-image: url('/images/menubar_bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu {
    padding:0px;
    height: 20px;
    list-style:none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1px auto;
}

#menu li {
    display:inline;
    padding: 0px 11px 0px 10px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    list-style:none;
    position: relative !important;
    background-image: url('/images/menu_item_tick.png');
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

I tried putting width:auto; on the UL element (#menu) but to no use... I want the UL element ot be centered and NOT 100% of the width automatically - it should adjust to the content, and the # of LI elements in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `float: left` from your `<li>` elements and the `<ul>` will center.

If you for some reason must have the `<li>` elements floated, look for info around horizontally-centered floated lists, such as explained here for example: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support.

Comment: I actually already had that before - what happened was that it would add extra margin between the LI elements that I do not need, and the UL is still 100% of the width. Only when I left-align the LIs, I get proper 0px margins between the LI tag elements.. .

Comment: I just changed the code to waht you mentioned, and you'll see - inconsistent gaps between the elements now makes the little white ticks off the location. Most of all, i just want to figure out fundamentally how to make the UL tag NOT become 940 pixels wide (the div is 940).

Comment: How about "padding: 0 12px 1px 7px" on your <li> elements?

Comment: That does work for the final visuals, but my purpose here is to understand HOW TO MAKE THE UL NOT BECOME 100% WIDTH if it doesn't need to be.

Comment: Basically you need to either give it a fixed width (and then "margin: 0 auto;"), or use floats. In the latter case, you need the implementation explained in the link I posted so you get floated elements to center horizontally.